# Can not instal Angular cli on MacOS High Sierra v10.13.2

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular-cli

I have a problem installing Angular cli. I Instal the latest **NodeJs v8.9.4** and **npm v5.6.0**. When I start installing **npm install -g @angular/cli** after that shows this message:

```
    npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
    npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
    npm ERR! code EACCES
    npm ERR! errno -13
    npm ERR! syscall access
    npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
    npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
    npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules\'',
    npm ERR!   errno: -13,
    npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
    npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
    npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

> Operating system: MacOS High Sierra v10.13.2

I am not expert but if I understand I do not have permission to install. Thank you for your help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for so long to reply. `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli` did not help me. I get the same result.

Basically, this is how I solve the problem.

**To not get "permission denied" to installing nodejs and npm on macOS High Sierra. I used https://brew.sh .** Allowed to install without errors or "permission denied".

Here is some source:

- https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#macos
- https://github.com/creationix/nvm/blob/master/README.md#mac-os-troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this:

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

and then enter your administrator password when prompted.

There's a debate on whether you should ever use sudo when using `npm install -g`, but I use sudo like this when I need to and haven't suffered for it.

Here's a similar stackoverflow question about this:
[npm throws error without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo)